# Remover barra de título Android - Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html5, apache-cordova

Estou criando um aplicativo Android pelo Cordova.

Ao abrir o APP ele aparece uma barra de título, em alguns aparelhos em azul, em outros em preto com o título. como segue à seguir:

*troquei o título e desconfigurei o ícone por motivos de sigilo da empresa*

[image: título]

Essa tela sempre aparece quando vou iniciar o APP.
Existe alguma configuração para impedir esse incomodo?

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto na sua activity.

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Assim a `ActionBar` será escondida.

Comment: Acho que essa não é uma solução viável para a aplicação, visto que o aplicativo está em FullScreen. A ActionBar não é o problema, essa barra que aparece ai é antes de o aplicativo rodar, assim que eu clico nele, ele aparenta essa barra como título e ícone.
Esse código não funcionou.